# Data is not displayed when bing map is scrolled

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

I am displaying my network data on Bing Map according to the location of a site.
When scrolled either up or down / left or right, the same network data which was displayed earlier on map is not displayed when the same location arrives during scrolling.

Not able to get the problem.

I have set the boundaries on Map:

```
private static Location _startPoint = new Location { Longitude = -175, Latitude = -65 };// defines the boundary of Map. A rectangle.
    private static Location _endPoint = new Location { Longitude = 168, Latitude = 82 };//botttom left is Origin, top Right is Max.
```

Perhaps this setting of boundary is causing a problem to display the data again.

This is the function I am using when user is scrolling and validating the area everytime user scrolls....  filter is the KPI filter that i am showing on Map.

```
public static KpiFilter ValidateSelectedAreaFilter(KpiFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters != null && filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.Count() > 0)
        {
            if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToArray()[0].BottomRight.Longitude < filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToArray()[0].TopLeft.Longitude)
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Longitude = _endPoint.Longitude;
        }

        if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters != null && filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.Count() > 0)
        {
            //Check if points are inside the map area. If all points are outside then don't do anything, just return empty object.
            if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Longitude < _startPoint.Longitude &&
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].TopLeft.Latitude < _startPoint.Latitude &&
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].TopLeft.Longitude > _endPoint.Longitude &&
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Latitude > _endPoint.Latitude)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // checks if the selected area intersects with Japan boundary. 
            // If some part of the selection is outside boundary, the selection is cropped so as to fit it within limits.

            //if some selection from left side is outside boundary, then topLeft(long) is set to Start Point Origin.
            if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].TopLeft.Longitude < _startPoint.Longitude)
            {
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].TopLeft.Longitude = _startPoint.Longitude;
            }
            //if some selection from bottom is outside boundary, then  bottomRight(lat) is set to Start Point Origin
            if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Latitude < _startPoint.Latitude)
            {
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Latitude = _startPoint.Latitude;
            }

            //if some selection from right is outside boundary, then  bottomRight(long) is set to End Point Max.
            if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Longitude > _endPoint.Longitude)
            {
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].BottomRight.Longitude = _endPoint.Longitude;
            }
            //if some selection from top is outside boundary, then topLeft(long) is set to End Point Max.
            if (filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].TopLeft.Latitude > _endPoint.Latitude)
            {
                filter.LocationFilters.RectangleAreaFilters.ToList()[0].TopLeft.Latitude = _endPoint.Latitude;
            }


        }
        else
            return null;

        return filter;
    }
```

XAML COde:

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl"


<m:Map
            x:Name="map" 
            MouseWheel="map_MouseWheel" 
            AnimationLevel="None"
            MouseDoubleClick="map_MouseDoubleClick"
            CredentialsProvider="your key"
            Mode="Road" 
            ZoomLevel="5" 
            Center="40.50,139.40" 
            Grid.Row = "1"   
            Grid.RowSpan="2">   
            <m:MapLayer
                x:Name="binLayer"
                CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
                Visibility="Visible" />
            <m:MapLayer 
                x:Name="pointDataLayer"
                Visibility="Visible" >
                <Canvas 
                    x:Name="canvasPointData" 
                    MouseRightButtonDown="canvasPointData_MouseRightButtonDown"/>

                <Grid 
                    x:Name="messageGrid"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Grid 
                        Background="White"
                        Width="Auto" 
                        Height="Auto" Opacity=".7">
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock 
                        x:Name="txbMessage"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0"/>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel 
                    x:Name="grdShowLabel"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Height="20" 
                    Width="Auto"
                    Margin="5,4"
                    Background="LightGray"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    VerticalAlignment="top">
                </StackPanel>
            </m:MapLayer>
            <m:MapLayer 
                    x:Name="dropCallLayer"
                    Visibility="Visible" >
                <Canvas 
                        x:Name="canvasdropCall" MouseRightButtonDown="canvasdropCall_MouseRightButtonDown"/>
            </m:MapLayer>
        </m:Map>
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps... Nobody can know this, as you haven't shown *how* you actually display your data. Show more of your code and XAML, but relevant parts only. Are you using a MapItemsControl?

Comment: @Clemens i have edited the code and have pasted it....

Comment: @Clemens have added XAML code also above..pls check it....

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your code. I am however quite sure that you shouldn't show your data in a Canvas inside a MapLayer. Use a MapItemsControl instead.

Comment: @Clemens data displayed is correct , no problem in that... but problem occurs only when map is scrolled and the world map starts repeating again.

Comment: As said before, use a MapItemsControl. It will keep the item at their location, even after changing the viewport.

Comment: @Clemens I will try and reply u soon